# Bash script to update PATH when VS code extension is updated

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote-ssh

I would like to be able to use `code` in the `remote-ssh` command. I have seen the answers [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867991/the-code-command-does-not-work-when-connecting-to-a-docker-container-remotely) and my settings for inheriting the environment were all checked out.

I would like to implement [this solution to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867991/the-code-command-does-not-work-when-connecting-to-a-docker-container-remotely#answer-64220542) but I don't have a fixed path as this extension gets updated and the directory changes. I know that the long number is the hash commit but and wouldn't want to get a script to read the code changes on github to do this. Is there a way to figure out what the most recently updated script and updating the `PATH` variable? Or is it better to add all the directories to the `PATH` variable?

I am unfamiliar with bash. I am using a Windows machine.